# Connect to external database in android development

Tags: android, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am develop a weather android app, and i need get all the data(wind speed, temp,  etc) from http://00.00.00.00/phpmyadmin/ this page, there have one database and three tables, and i know the user name and password, just no idea how to connect the table in that phpmyadmin page and get weather data that i want.

Can anyone give me an example about how to achieve that? 
Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for security issues, I recommend you remove the right url from your question.

You have to make some kind of web service to speak with your Android app. For example, make a PHP script that runs local in your server and get all the data you need from mysql. Then, make a HTTP request from your android app and get the result.

Comment: thanks i block the right url, and i can not make a PHP script in the serevr, because that is not my server.

Comment: Is there have another method?